# What is wrong with my topology sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```js
var input = ["KittenService: ", "Leetmeme: Cyberportal", "Cyberportal: Ice", "CamelCaser: KittenService", "Fraudstream: Leetmeme", "Ice: "];

var output = [];

function valid(input) {
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var array = input[i].trim().split(':');
    var packageName = array[0].trim();
    var dependencyName = array[1].trim();
    if (array.length > 1 && dependencyName === '') {

      if (output.indexOf(packageName) === -1) {
        output.push(packageName);
      } else {
        return;
      }
    } else if (array.length > 1 && dependencyName !== '') {
      if (output.indexOf(dependencyName) === -1) {
        output.push(dependencyName);
        if (output.indexOf(dependencyName) > -1) {
          if (output.indexOf(packageName) > -1) {
            continue;
          } else {
            output.push(packageName);
          }
        }
      } else if (output.indexOf(dependencyName) > -1) {
        output.push(packageName);
      }
    }
  }
  return output.join(', ');
}
valid(input);

console.log(output);
```

I am trying to figure out a way to get the following output:

> "KittenService, Ice, Cyberportal, Leetmeme, CamelCaser, Fraudstream"

Right now it logs:

> 'KittenService, Cyberportal, Leetmeme, Ice, CamelCaser, Fraudstream'

I heard topology sort can fix this, but I am not sure how to implement tsort. How can I do this, or there is other method I can use to fix this? I want to do this without additional library.

Comment: how does the topology look like?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting
I am not sure how to do this.  So currently finding different way to figure the problem out.

Comment: right, and which one?

Comment: By looking at it I would say Depth-first search.

Comment: some nodes are not liked, like the group KittenService/CamelCaser.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

1. The second `push` in your code is not verifying whether the item that is pushed has some dependencies. For example, the dependency `Cyberportal` is pushed, but you did not check whether there is maybe a pair where `Cyberportal` itself has a dependency: which there is... In general, this might then also repeat for the dependency you may find: that also can have another dependency. So you need an iterative or recursive solution here.
2. The `return` after the first `else` is wrong. In some cases this will make your output incomplete. Try your code with the same input, but then `"CamelCaser: KittenService"` moved to the start of the input array. You'll only get two elements in your output because of this bug.
3. It is useless to check just after that push whether the pushed element is in the array. You don't need that first `if (output.indexOf(dependencyName) > -1)`: it will always be true.
4. The other occurrence of `if (output.indexOf(dependencyName) > -1)` is also useless, as it also will always be true.
5. It is useless to check for `array.length > 1` when you have just applied a method (`trim()`) to the second element.
6. You should not let a function put its result in a global variable. Instead create `output` as a variable local to the function, and return that variable (not a `.join()` result).
7. Even with corrections, the algorithm does not have a linear time complexity, since you have `indexOf` (which is *O(n)*) within a loop that is also *O(n)*, resulting in a *O(n²)* time complexity. Yet this can be done in linear time.

#### Solution

I assume that a certain value is only dependent on at most one other element -- not counting indirect dependencies via that single dependency --, as your notation (with the colon) seems to imply that.

My suggestion is to make use of hash tables, using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which provide constant access to their elements. Secondly, with recursion you can make sure to output an element's dependencies first before outputting the element itself.

Here is the ES6 code:

```js
function valid(input) {
    let result = new Set(),
        pairs = new Map(input.map(s => s.split(': '))),
        loop = (_, key) => { // Recursive function to add key with dependencies
            if (pairs.get(key)) { // Has dependency
                loop(_, pairs.get(key)); // Recurse to add dependencies first 
                pairs.set(key, null); // Clear dependency
            }
            // After dependencies were added, now add this key
            result.add(key); // Duplicates are ignored
        };
    pairs.forEach(loop); // Call loop for every element
    return [...result]; // Convert Set to Array: order is kept
}

// Sample run:
var input = ["KittenService: ", "Leetmeme: Cyberportal", "Cyberportal: Ice",
             "CamelCaser: KittenService", "Fraudstream: Leetmeme", "Ice: "];
var result = valid(input);
console.log(result);
```

If you do not have ES6 support, you can use plain objects instead of Set and Map. And use normal `function`s instead of arrow notation.